# split stateless component into smaller part

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <div>
       <div>Block A</div>
       <div>Block B</div>
    </div>
)
export default MyComponent
```

How to I split above component without create another new file? I want to reuse `<div>Block A</div>` If it's stateful component I can simply split them into function and render them like `{this.renderBlockA()}` and `{this.renderBlockB()}`

Comment: Why would you want to split components without creating new file though? Clarify: I think you should always put components in separate files.

Comment: @AVAVT I don't want to create too many files. Each file can contain multiple components

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create these small components in the same file

```
export const BlockA = () => <div>Block A</div>
export const BlockB = () => <div>Block B</div>

const MyComponent = () => (
    <div>
       <BlockA/>
       <BlockB/>
    </div>
)
export default MyComponent
```

Comment: but can other file use BlockA? like `import { BlockA } from 'myComponent'`?

Comment: yes it can, but you may cut off exports if you don't want others to reuse these components from outside

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask yourself a question:

"Do I need state and lifecycle methods?" You can find more on this subject [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

If you need a stateful, es6 class component you can simply create one in the same file. [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

If you only need a dumb(stateless) component], which is basically just representation of your UI, you can write a [function component](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) in the same file, or use something like [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) or [glamorous](https://github.com/paypal/glamorous) to generate you html elements with styles.